# Sismo - PHP Fatal error: Class 'Sismo\GrowlNotifier' not found

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, continuous-integration

Trying to setup Sismo , running php sismo.php results in :

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Sismo\GrowlNotifier' not found

My config is setup in the default `~/.sismo/config.php` location

and the line is:

```
$notifier = new Sismo\GrowlNotifier('pa$$word');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct FQCN is `Sismo\Notifier\GrowlNotifier`.